# Depending on read models to build other read model

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I wonder if using other read models to update my particurlar read model is considered good practice. For example there are two agreggate roots: User and Report. To build Report query I need current state of User and I already have read model that provides me with that information. May I use it or should I rebuild my query depends only on events (from different agreggates)?

One problem I see in this approach is that I may want to get User in state at particular date from the past in those reports. And of course I leave out keeping reads up-to-date problems.

Maybe I just may build supporting users table for reports query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how decoupled you want the too read-models to be.

1. If you want a microservice type of decoupling (a loose one) the Reports read-model should depend only on the events generated by the User AR; in this case you must create another read-model that captures only the interesting events from the User AR (UserWasCreated, UserHasChangedHisUsername etc) and the Reports read-model should use this local read-model. When rebuilding the Reports read-model you could also rebuild the local users read-model and you get the state of a user at that particular moment in the past (the two read-models are being rebuild synchronously).  This require more code, but it give you a decoupled system.
2. If you want a monolitic system then the Reports read-model could query the Users read-model; in this case, it is impossible to get the state of a user at a moment in the past as the Users read-model reflects (probably) the latest state.